# Wordpress add Password protected hide content in PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-protector/

Password protected content

Enter the correct password to view the content

```
[passster password="123456"]Your content here[/passster]
```

I don't know how to use shortcode in PHP

```html
<!--<hide content>-->
<ul class="TPlayerNv">
    <?php echo $optplayer; ?>
</ul>
<div class="TPlayerCn BgA">
    <div class="EcBgA" style="background-color:#EEEEEE!important;"> 
        <div class="TPlayer">
            <?php echo $player; ?>
            <span class="AAIco-lightbulb_outline lgtbx-lnk"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="lgtbx"></span>
<!--</hide content>-->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress – How to use shortcode in php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273197/wordpress-how-to-use-shortcode-in-php-files)

Answer (score 0):

A normal way to call a shortcode in any PHP file is given below :

```
<?php 

 echo do_shortcode('[passster password="123456"]Your content here[/passster]');

?>
```

Hope it helps you to get the desired output. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress to write shortcode, please check below link.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>
```